# In $\mathbb{N}$: Prove that $a\mid b$ is antisymmetric

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

> In $\mathbb{N}$: Prove that $a\mid b$ is antisymmetric

I started with $a = bk$ and $ b = aq$ and replace one on another and got $1 = kq.$

My professor said that since we’re working with natural numbers $q = 1$ and $k = 1$ and so $a = b.$

But by division definition $k$ and $q$ are integer numbers, not natural. So if both $q$ and $k$ are $-1$ then a isn’t necessarily equal to b. Am I right or did I get something wrong?

Comment: Either $k=q=1$ or $k=q=-1$. But the latter would contradict the assumption that $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers.

Comment: unless $a=b=0,$ but then $a=b.$ @MatthewLeingang (Assuming the modern convention that $0\in\mathbb N.$)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Good point; OP used the assumption that $ab\neq 0$ when arriving at $kq=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a,b\in\Bbb N$, we have $a,b\ge 0$. If either $k$ or $q$ were negative, then so would either $a$ or $b$.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, @GZanotto :)

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest alternative way to avoid confusion. If $a|b$ then clearly $a \leq b$. Similarly if $b|a$ then $ b \leq a$. Therefore it follows that $a=b$.